# OpenCV cannot find chessboard corners in fish-eye images

Tags: opencv, camera, camera-calibration, fisheye

I am using OpenCV3.0 and VS2013 to do fisheye wide-angle(185 deg) camera calibration. There are some pictures that can work well, e.g:

[image: Chessboard to be detected-- fish-eye]

and the correction result is satisfying as:

![corrected image -- fish-eye][2]

The result looks good, but I use a similar image to do calibration instead, it cannot find any chessboard corners!! The image is like this:

[image: another chessboard image]

The results are very confusing to me since I try many many similar images( same distance different angel, same angel different distance ) for about 60 images, and small part of them can be detected. I use 2592x1944 resolution BMP files, and I accurately put the chessboard center in the center of camera, but the result is no good than the casually captured images, some even cannot find corners. 
I use this code to detect:

```
bool patternfound = findChessboardCorners(imageGray, board_size, corners,CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE+ 
        CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK );
```

Comment: I doubt it is supposed to work with fish-eye at all

Comment: @AndreyKamaev, thanks for reply! You mean the function findChessBoardCorner doesn't meant to work with fish-eye images?  But small part of  my images can work well, they can be calibrated well and make  good correction results.  I am sorry i cannot upload many images.

Comment: Have you seen this http://abarry.org/wide-angle-lens-stereo-calibration-with-opencv/ ?

Comment: The link to your second image is missing.

Comment: @techraf, sorry, i cannot upload more than 2 images, the second image is well defished, just like the normal pinhole image taken from ordinary camera or phone.

Comment: @AndreyKamaev, i have seen this website, and it doesn't work. Do you have any other points? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turn off
CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK , when testing fisheye image.